# Asp.Net MVC 5 Project on IIS, Login failed DOMAIN\MACHINE$ for Sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, iis, iis-10

I am developing a website with the Asp.net MVC5 template. This website have obviously a database with some informations. This MS-Sql database runs on a remote VM. While coding I tested this site with the integrated IIS Express and the mentioned database.

Now I wanted to publish this website on a real IIS 10.0 Server, this IIS Server runs on the same VM as the database.

I published the website as follow:

Right click on project in VS15 > Publish > File System (Publish Method) > Copied the compiled data to the mentioned VM > In the IIS Manager I created a new website based on the compiled source data.

**Now the problem:**

When I try to run this website (localhost or via remote from my client) the following error occurs:

> Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'.

This two connectionstrings are in my web.config, both are autogenerated from Asp.Net Frameork:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="InfoScreenContext" connectionString="data source=vsdev1972\;initial catalog=InfoScreen;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="UserProfile" connectionString="data source=vsdev1972\;initial catalog=InfoScreen;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I was searching a whole day for a solution but none of these approaches worked for me:

- Adding this DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$ user to the database users
- Enabled Windows Authentication in IIS Manager
- Tried to edit the connection string
- Granted source access for everyone

Any ideas? If u need any further informations pls contact me!

Comment: You're connecting to your database using integrated security, which means it uses the same user that is running your app pool. Make sure that user has DB permission.